# Screen-like split screen for output of multiprocess python

Tags: python, terminal, multiprocessing, tmux, gnu-screen

I'm often in the situation that I have to run some time-intensive code on a larg number of inputs, and want to speed it up running multiple instances of the code in parallel (on different CPU-cores or Cuda-devices).

So far I done it by hand:

- Open screen/tmux
- create split-planes
- run the code with only a fraction of the inputs in each pane

This is however cumbersome, error-prone and doesn't work in cases where the are non-parallel parts of code. I therefore sometimes used multiprocessing.Pool to run the code in parallel but this does not work if I want/need to be able to read the output of the different parts and will get a mess if the (third-party) code that runs in parallel contains things like tqdm.

I would like create a split screen and write the stdout/stderr of each of the different processes to one of the split panes. I however haven't found any package/trick to do this properly.
I played with urwind, ncurses & prompt_toolkit but they are not meant to serve stdout/stderr.

My current best – hacky – solution is using libtmux:

```
import os
import sys
import tempfile
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process

import libtmux
from tqdm import tqdm

tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
fifo1_name = os.path.join(tmpdir, "fifo1")
fifo2_name = os.path.join(tmpdir, "fifo2")
os.mkfifo(fifo1_name)
os.mkfifo(fifo2_name)
session_name = "session_name"


def setup(para):
    """Change stdout/stderr to point to the fifo connected to the right tmux plane"""
    pid = int(current_process().name.split("-")[-1])
    if pid % 2 == 0:
        fifo_write = open(fifo1_name, "w", 1)
    else:
        fifo_write = open(fifo2_name, "w", 1)
    sys.stdout = fifo_write
    sys.stderr = fifo_write
    run(para, pid)


def run(para, pid):
    """Dummy function"""
    print("start run nr.", para, "on", pid)
    for _ in tqdm(range(10), desc=str(para)):
        time.sleep(1)
    print("finished run nr.", para)


parameter_space = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

# Set up tmux
server = libtmux.Server()
session = server.find_where({"session_name": session_name})
if session is None:
    session = server.new_session(
        session_name=session_name, window_command="cat " + fifo1_name
    )
    window = session.windows[0]
    window.panes[0]
    window.split_window(shell="cat " + fifo2_name)
# session.attach_session() Does not work for unknown reasons the planes stay empty

# Run always 2 runs in parallel
with Pool(2) as p:
    p.map(setup, parameter_space)

if session:
    session.kill_session()
```

This still has the problem, that I must manually attach to the session, since `attach_session()` leads to empty panes. Also it feels like a hacky and ugly workaround.

Is there a better/nicer way?

Comment: Write to files, create tmux separate tmux startup script which splits the screen and `tail -f` those files? Still hacky, of course.

Comment: For a non-programming solution you might like to write to separate files and use `multitail` to view them.